# We are facing "PANIC: could not read from control file:Success

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

archive_mode is turned on unfortunately in my Postgres 9.2 database.

Due to that disk space is full 100%. We have removed few old xlog files and truned off the archive_mode.  Now space is available.But still we are facing below problem when we try to start the database using pg_ctl -D command.

PANIC: could not read from control file:Success

Comment: did you remove xlog from pg_archive right? not pg_xlog, did you see your log for more details?

Comment: yes. Now space is available but we are facing the problem. How to proceed further.